# Projection of aerial image using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, usgs

I am having a very hard time with a USGS Declass3 image (D3C1210-200272A025).
I have already tried different projections, unfortunately without success.

For sure, the problem is me, but I don't know how to use the given metadata to fit the image(s).

The images are not georeferenced but after some time I realized that I should use the given metadata of the image, but it didn't help me a lot.

After a look at the metadata I found `"Center Lat dec"`, `"Center Long dec"` and `"NW Corner Lat dec"`, `"NW Corner Long dec"` (same for NE,SE,SW).
I just don't realize how I should use that information to put my 7 images into the correct spatial location.
When I drop the images into QGIS they all fall on to the same area.

I got the image from https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov

The image and metadata can be found via
Tab 2 - Data Sets > Select Declassified Data > Select Declass 3
Tab 3 - Additional Criteria > "D3C1210-200272A025" (Entity ID)
Tab 4 - Results > Show Metadata (4th icon) to view the coordinates

Comment: Can you link to the file or describe where you got it from? To save us having to search for it?

Comment: Think I've found it from USGS Earth Explorer via giving it the entity ID of your "D3C...." etc code. The download is 4.2Gb though. Clicking the image in the preview gives a very raw image montage with photographic borders etc that might not even be NS aligned or in a flat projection. What does yours look like?

Comment: All seven images together are 4,2Gb in size (each around 800Mb). There is no correction done on the pictures.

Comment: The "Footprint" is a trapezoid because its not had any planimetric correction to make it an orthophoto. Given the corner coordinates from the metadata you could use the georeferencer to warp and reproject to that trapezoid though. I can do that with the 9Mb jpeg (but 4Gb of hi-res is going to take hours to download and a while to warp...)

Comment: would you please be so kind to describe that process a little bit? I'm afraid i'm not exactly sure where to find georeferencer. I tried GDAL/transform(reproject) - but it crashed 3 times in a row

Comment: I think this might be worth writing as an answer now. But it might be different for the 4Gb data set which I've not seen.

Comment: thank you for your effort. I will still try to solve it somehow. Starting with clipping a small area - my area of interest.So the image will be much smaller in size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The USGS preview page has a JPEG image that is about 9Mb which looks like this (ignore the red dots for now):

[image]

The metadata lists four corner points which I shall assume are the corner points of the extent of useful map info in that image, ie ignoring the black border. That's what the red dots are.

I put the four corner points into a CSV file and loaded into QGIS:

```
NW 47.901 12.315
NE 47.621 15.113
SE 47.417 15.001
SW 47.746 12.293
```

and that puts them here across Austria, which looks like the footprint points on the USGS site also:

[image]

Now I use the Raster... Georeferencer... tool. With that I can click on each of the four corners of the image (which is what where the red dots came from) and then relate them to a geographic coordinate by using "From Map Canvas" and choosing the corresponding lat-long point from the CSV. You could even type the coordinates in directly:

[image]

Once all four are done, the image can be warped using one of the methods that can turn a rectangle into a trapezoid, such as the Thin Plate Spline.

But I can't get consistent accuracy across the whole image. Hard to tell without some vectors I can overlay, but here's the raster transparent on OpenStreetMap - the lake lines up nicely in the NW:

[image]

But in the SE there's a quarry in the photo that doesn't line up with the one in OSM:

[image]

You can see its "shadow" from the satellite pic in this blended image.

Accuracy could be improved by identifying more than just the corner points with points on the map - for example I can see some towns and roads (and the quarry) etc. By adding extra control points in the Georeferencer you can squeeze and shape this image to match the modern map. But you might need a lot of control points depending on the degree of accuracy you need.

I've just gone through and found a bunch of corresponding points (road junctions, airport runways, bridges, towns etc) and you can see perhaps now how non-linear the image was with this result:

[image]

As I said, I don't know how this image corresponds to the 4Gb data set, but the same thing could be done in principle.

Comment: ohw man that looks great. I will try that tomorrow (too tired) - but i think this solved my problem!